# Verifying external data using model determined using cross validation

Tags: python, cross-validation

I am learning data mining in Python. I am trying out cross validation.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
X = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])
Y = np.array([False,True,True,False])
kf=KFold(4,n_folds=2)
for train_index, test_index in kf:
   X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
   Y_train, Y_test = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]
```

Now I have a new list. `X=[0.25,0.33,0.21,0.101];Y=[True, False, False, True]` How can I verify the results as per the model determined using the above code?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean to verify and how.

Comment: Please Read The Fine Manual: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `KFold` function has nothing to do with model determination.

It just splits the data and labels to folds.

If you add to the loop:

```
    print(X_train, X_test)
    print(Y_train, Y_test)
```

You can see the folds at each iteration:

```
# Iteration 1
# Train           Test 
  [ 0.3  0.4]     [ 0.1  0.2]
  [ True False]   [False  True]
# Iteration 2
# Train           Test 
  [ 0.1  0.2]     [ 0.3  0.4]
  [False  True]   [ True False]
```